# Application data Not visible in cloudhub

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, cloudhub

I have used objectstore in my application and app deploy on cloudhub.
Cloudhub not showing objectstore in application data.
Code:

```
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" key="new" value-ref="#['kalpesh']" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
    <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore" key="new" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Cloudhub default store  `_defaultUserObjectStore`for it to appear in 'Application Data':

```
object-store-ref="_defaultUserObjectStore"
```

Comment: why its not working when i was provide 'partition=default' in objectstore global element.